# Is there a US national plan for increasing renewable energy sources?

Tags: united-states, environmental-policy

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Energy_for_America), there was a plan called New Energy for America:

> New Energy for America was a plan led by Barack Obama and Joe Biden to
>   invest in renewable energy sources, reduce reliance on foreign oil,
>   address global warming issues, and create jobs for Americans.

It is not clear from the article if this plan is active or not, although the past tense suggests it is no longer valid.

According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewable_energy_in_the_United_States):

> Renewable energy accounted for 12.2 % of total primary energy
>   consumption[3](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Renewable_energy_statistics#Consumption_of_energy_from_renewable_sources) and 14.94 % of the domestically produced electricity in
>   the United States in 2016.

This figure is [about the same as in EU](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Renewable_energy_statistics#Consumption_of_energy_from_renewable_sources):

> Renewable energy sources accounted for a 13.2 % share of the EU-28’s
>   gross inland energy consumption in 2016.

However, EU [has a plan to significantly increase this percentage in the future](https://ec.europa.eu/energy/en/topics/renewable-energy):

> The EU's Renewable energy directive sets **a binding target of 20% final
>   energy consumption from renewable sources by 2020**. To achieve this, EU
>   countries have committed to reaching their own national renewables
>   targets ranging from 10% in Malta to 49% in Sweden. They are also each
>   required to have at least 10% of their transport fuels come from
>   renewable sources by 2020.

I am wondering if a similar plan exists in the US.

**Question:** Is there a US national plan for increasing renewable energy sources?

Comment: Not a full answer, but if you want to see every US state's individual plan, [this is a good list from 2017](http://www.ncsl.org/research/energy/renewable-portfolio-standards.aspx).

Comment: @Giter that's pretty close to the core of my answer so I'm taking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR The US is not committed to a national reduction, but there is a lot of meaningful progress and many commitments to sustainability in the US.

---

The current president has de-prioritized nation wide goals which were established by the previous administration, but there are still [programs](https://www.energy.gov/eere/services/states-and-local-communities) to help state or local governments achieve results. Many states and cities have made independent commitments to reductions; [CA](http://www.energy.ca.gov/commission/fact_sheets/climate_commitments_fact_sheets.html), [HI](https://governor.hawaii.gov/newsroom/press-release-governor-ige-signs-bill-setting-100-percent-renewable-energy-goal-in-power-sector/), [NY](https://energyplan.ny.gov/), [Clean Cities](https://cleancities.energy.gov/accomplishments/).  [The department of energy](https://www.energy.gov/eere/efficiency/government-energy-management) has similar goals for federal reductions in use of energy.

Several [sub-units](https://www.sierraclub.org/ready-for-100/commitments) (including the state of Hawaii) have gone so far as to commit to 0% fossil fuel over some time frame, and some (towns) have already achieved it.

---

from [Giter](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30001/is-there-a-us-national-plan-for-increasing-renewable-energy-sources#comment108530_30001): [a list every state's plan](http://www.ncsl.org/research/energy/renewable-portfolio-standards.aspx)